# I have problem with a plus in JS, I'm using node.js and fs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need that my code pluses `1` to some numbers, but if, for example, it receives `1`, I get `11`, not  `2`.

```
          fs.readFile(`${dir}/warns/${mentioned.id}.txt`, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
              var x = data;
              var y = 1;
              var z = x + y;
              fs.writeFile(`${dir}/warns/${mentioned.id}.txt`, `${z}`, 'utf8', function(err, result) {
                 if(err) console.log('error', err);
          });
          });
      };
```

Comment: `data` is a **string** so you have to explicitly force it to be a number.

Comment: `1 + 1 === 2`, `1 + "1" === "11"`

Comment: You are receiving your value as a string. You must convert it to a number. For example, `var x = +data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the text before doing the operation. Like this

```
var x = parseInt(data, 10);
```

in javascript string 1 with numeric 1 will concatenate.

Comment: This *might* be appropriate, but we don't know if `data` might have a fractional part.